# How to group multiple rows under one group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following 3 tables: [image]

I need to retrieve the following by joining the 3 tables: 
show all the sub_questions under one question_id and show each question_id under one questions_category.

======================================================================
questions_category || question_id ||sub_question =========================================================================== this is the category1|| question *1 || this is the subquestion* grouped by question _1 ===========================================================================***********************|| *************|| this is a second subquestion grouped by question _1 ===========================================================================***********************|| *************|| this is a second subquestion grouped by question _1
=========================================================================== ***********************|| question *2 || this is the subquestion* grouped by question_2 ===========================================================================***********************|| ************* || this is the subquestion_ grouped by question_2

I hope it makes sense. Is it possible to do in mysql?

Comment: This is something probably handled better in your presentation layer.

Comment: Argh. My eyes!!!

Comment: @Strawberry I feel your pain